# New xamarin.forms project creation gives NU11002 Unable to find package Xamarin.Forms with version (>= 250121934.0.0)

Tags: xamarin.forms

Recently i updated my visual studio 2017 enterprise to 15.5.0. I am trying to create xamarin forms project as Blank App, platfom Android + ios, UI Technology Xamarin.Forms, code sharing strategy .net standart. When i try to build the default created project i got the following error;

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error NU1102  Unable to find package Xamarin.Forms with version (>=
>   250121934.0.0)
>     - Found 163 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 2.5.0.121934 ]
>     - Found 0 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages

I can not also remove and install xamarin.forms nuget. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Install xamarin.forms on all projects, in my case I was missing in the iOS project, it was enough to install the xamarin.forms nuget and everything worked normally. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

i finally found the solution. I opened android sdk manager and install Android 7.1 Nougat SDK (previously android 6.0 was installed). Then i right clicked solution and opened nuget manager. I selected Xamarin.forms package and choose the latest version of package and click install. I refreshed the package in all projects. Now everything works well.

Comment: And surely don't forget to select the target framework of your android project as Android 7.1